# Timer.scheduled(); I cannot stop variable++ cycle

Tags: swift, timer, cycle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wavz2.png)

How i can stop a cycle?

### Code 1

```
 @objc func dismissImageView() {
    timer1 = Timer()
    timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(timerWillDisappear), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
}
```

### Code 2

```
   **When i touch on myView - timer's beginning and don't stop!**
@objc func timerWillDisappear() {
    if repeatsVar != 1.0 {
        repeatsVar! += 0.01
    } 
}
```

### Code 3

```
else if repeatsVar == 1.0 { **This if doesn't work!!!**
            timer1.invalidate()
            timer1 = nil
            repeatsVar! -= 1
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```

Comment: timerWillDisappear  check my checking once; and i cannot use timer1.invalide()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers have some error to them. You likely won't get a value that is exactly 1.0. Since you stop as soon as you value gets to 1.0, why not check to see if it is less than 1.0 instead?

```
@objc func timerWillDisappear() {
    if repeatsVar < 1.0 {
        repeatsVar += 0.01
    } else 
        timer1.invalidate()
        timer1 = nil
        repeatsVar = 0
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Also note that your `dismissImageView()` method should not create an empty timer and then a scheduled timer:

```
@objc func dismissImageView() {
    //timer1 = Timer() <- Get rid of this line.
    timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(timerWillDisappear), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: You should also change your `repeatsVar` so that it is not an Optional. There's no reason for that. (Get rid of the `?` in its definition.